# make a php page load another php script server to server communication

Tags: php, communication

I've tried looking for a solution to this issue for a few days now and am getting quite confused.

Aim:

> To have a PHP server ("Server A") communicate directly to another PHP
>   server ("Server B") when Server A is visited by user. It then sends a
>   query string to Server B to add in to Server B's database.

Full story:

> A visitor will visit Server A and register to their website, as part
>   of their registration Server A will write to Server A's database with
>   all the visitors information. At this point I'd like Server A to load
>   a .php file on Server B and send a query string with it, for example:
>   http://example.com/api/add.php?name=Craig&age=21&key=32r932r9832yr813hr813rh1389ry13r7y31r.
>   Server B, having a PHP file requested from it, will take the variables
>   and run the script on add.php (take the variables and add it to it's
>   database).

**Important note: I don't want the client machine to know this, initially I wanted to use JQUERY but realised this sends the request from the client machine and not the server directly.**

What is the best way to do this?

*Many thanks in advance!*

Craig

Comment: Maybe looking for cURL? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: What you need is a webservice, which can be implemented via protocols like REST or SOAP. Or just call a script via cURL, as @jeremyharris suggested.

Comment: I had looked at cURL but didn't understand it... how would I load a URL with a query string using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Learn cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Here is [an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to get you started:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/api/add.php?name=Craig&age=21&key=32r932r9832yr813hr813rh1389ry13r7y31r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```